# Simplfying complex rational expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

I'm trying to simplify
$$
\frac {\dfrac {x}{y} - \dfrac {y}{x}}{y}.$$
My method of trying to solve this is try to simplify the numerator $\frac {x}{y}-\frac{y}{x}$ Then I find the GCD: $xy$, multiply, $\frac{xy}{xy}-\frac{xy}{xy} = 0$, (I know this part is wrong but I don't know why).

Multiply by reciprocal of $y$,  $0 \cdot \frac{1}{y} = 0$. Anyway, that's all wrong since the textbook lists the correct answer as $\frac{x^2-y^2}{xy^2}$. How do you simplify this step by step? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know this part is wrong but I don't know why

You start with $\frac{x}{y} - \frac{y}{x}$.  You found the correct GCD.  It's $xy$.  So you want the denominators to be $xy$.  Then you need to multiply $\frac{x}{y}$ by $\color{blue}x$ on the top and bottom, and multiply $\frac{y}{x}$ by $\color{red}y$ on the top and bottom:

$$ \frac{x}{y} - \frac{y}{x} = \frac{x}{y} \cdot \color{blue}{\frac{x}{x}}  - \frac{y}{x} \cdot \color{red}{\frac{y}{y}} = \frac{x^2}{yx} - \frac{y^2}{xy} = \frac{x^2-y^2}{xy}$$

Then you can continue:

$$\frac{\frac{x}{y} - \frac{y}{x}}{y} = \frac{\frac{x^2-y^2}{xy}}{y} = \frac{x^2-y^2}{xy} \cdot \frac{1}{y} = \frac{x^2-y^2}{xy^2}$$

Here's another way to do it from the beginning:

\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{x}{y} - \frac{y}{x}}{y} &= \frac{\frac{x}{y} - \frac{y}{x}}{y} \cdot \frac{xy}{xy}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{\left(\frac{x}{y} - \frac{y}{x}\right) xy}{y \cdot xy}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{\frac{x}{y} \cdot xy - \frac{y}{x} \cdot xy}{xy^2}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{x^2 - y^2}{xy^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. My problem was trying to multiply $$\frac{x}{y} \cdot \frac{x}{x}$$ in my head instead of writing it out. Lesson learned!

Comment: Been there, for sure.

Answer (score 3):

The numerator is
$$
\frac{x}{y}-\frac{y}{x}=\frac{x^2}{xy}-\frac{y^2}{xy}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{xy}
$$
so you finally get
$$
\frac{x^2-y^2}{xy}\,\frac{1}{y}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{xy^2}
$$
Note that the reciprocal of $y$ is $\dfrac{1}{y}$.

Comment: D'oh, I see it now. I don't know why my brain made $\frac{x}{y} \cdot \frac {x}{x} = \frac {xy}{xy}$...

Thanks egreg!